# How do I get GCC and Make to exclusively use RAM only?

Tags: linux, make, gcc, ramdisk

I'm compiling a C++ project using GCC and Make. 
I use a ramdisk for this because it builds faster that way and to reduce the amount of writes to my SSD.

I've noticed that, despite moving the project to the ramdisk before building, I still get writes on my SSD. I have to build it many times a day and this would add up fast, reducing the SSD lifespan.

Is there a way to make GCC and Make exclusively use my ramdisk instead?

I've tried the -pipe option but it still wrote to my SSD instead of just memory.

I've also tried the --save-temps=obj option. This works, but the temporary files are large in size and my ramdisk gets full quite quickly. Without the temporary files I have enough memory for this, but manually deleting them after every build gets tedious.

Is there a way to do this without using alot of RAM? Like having the temporary files saved but deleted immediately after they're no longer needed.

Comment: You do understand, the writes on the SSD, are the temporary files being created.  The temporary files, should be deleted after the compile is completed, is that not happening?

Comment: It amazes me that even to this day, people are afraid to write to their SSD.  I write multiple gigabytes daily to my SSD.  Ive had the drive 4 years and it at 98% health.  Your will replace your computer before you need to replace the SSD.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I know. I want the same thing to happen but on the ramdisk instead.

Comment: @Keltari I'm writing a few hundred GBs a day. The maximum amount of writes for the SSD is 180TB so it wouldn't last longer than 2-3 years if I kept up like this.

Comment: @rcr - But you did make the temporary files write to the RAM disk, but it filled up the disk, sounds like you need a something other then just your SSD to store the files at.  I assume you ran `gcc -save-temps=obj -o dir/foo.o foo.c` sounds like a case where you can create a bat script that compiles then deletes the temporary file after the compile is done.

Comment: So I think what the author wants to do, is create the object file in memory, but they are going to have the same problem they have with their RAMDisk and it will take a lot of memory to do that.  The simplest solution is to not create the object file, but depending on their workflow, this might not be possible.